# Upscalling multiindex dataframe in pandas 1.3

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to increase the time resolution (upscaling) a DataFrame. I found several solutions but nothing works for Pandas 1.3.

My DataFrame has this shape.

```
                                              Population (cap)
country category   date                                       
FR      Population 2018-01-01 00:00:00+00:00        67101930.0
                   2019-01-01 00:00:00+00:00        67248926.0
                   2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00        67391582.0
DE      Population 2018-01-01 00:00:00+00:00        82905782.0
                   2019-01-01 00:00:00+00:00        83092962.0
                   2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00        83240525.0
```

I tried different codes like this one:

```py
    data = data.groupby(level=["country", "category"])
    data = data.resample(freq)
    data = data.ffill()
```

Unfortunately, this does not work and make the error: `MultiIndex has no single backing array. Use 'MultiIndex.to_numpy()' to get a NumPy array of tuples.`

Or this one:

```py
    data = data.reset_index()
    data = data.set_index(["date"])
    data = data.resample(freq)
    data = data.ffill()
    data = data.reset_index()
    data = data.set_index(["country", "category", "date"])
```

Which throw the error: `cannot reindex a non-unique index with a method or limit`.

How could I perform this task in Pandas 1.3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the current format is not conducive to this operation in pandas. The MultiIndex will need reset, leaving only `date` in the index. Then [`groupby resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html) can be used:

```
freq = '6M'
df = (
    df.reset_index(["country", "category"])  # Leave Date as the only index
        .groupby(["country", "category"], as_index=False)  # Groupby 
        .resample(freq)  # Resample at frequency
        .ffill()  # Whatever resampling operation here
)
```

`df`:

```
                            country    category  Population (cap)
  date                                                           
0 2018-01-31 00:00:00+00:00      DE  Population                 4
  2018-07-31 00:00:00+00:00      DE  Population                 4
  2019-01-31 00:00:00+00:00      DE  Population                 5
  2019-07-31 00:00:00+00:00      DE  Population                 5
  2020-01-31 00:00:00+00:00      DE  Population                 6
1 2018-01-31 00:00:00+00:00      FR  Population                 1
  2018-07-31 00:00:00+00:00      FR  Population                 1
  2019-01-31 00:00:00+00:00      FR  Population                 2
  2019-07-31 00:00:00+00:00      FR  Population                 2
  2020-01-31 00:00:00+00:00      FR  Population                 3
```

Some cleanup can be done with [`drop_level`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html#pandas-dataframe-droplevel), [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to return to initial shape:

```
freq = '6M'
df = (
    df.reset_index(["country", "category"])
        .groupby(["country", "category"], as_index=False)
        .resample(freq)
        .ffill()
        .droplevel(0)  # Remove added numerical index
        .reset_index() 
        .set_index(['country', 'category', 'date'])  # Restore MultiIndex
)
```

`df`:

```
                                              Population (cap)
country category   date                                       
DE      Population 2018-01-31 00:00:00+00:00                 4
                   2018-07-31 00:00:00+00:00                 4
                   2019-01-31 00:00:00+00:00                 5
                   2019-07-31 00:00:00+00:00                 5
                   2020-01-31 00:00:00+00:00                 6
FR      Population 2018-01-31 00:00:00+00:00                 1
                   2018-07-31 00:00:00+00:00                 1
                   2019-01-31 00:00:00+00:00                 2
                   2019-07-31 00:00:00+00:00                 2
                   2020-01-31 00:00:00+00:00                 3
```

---

DataFrame and imports used:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Population (cap)': {
        ('FR', 'Population',
         pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')): 1,
        ('FR', 'Population',
         pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')): 2,
        ('FR', 'Population',
         pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')): 3,
        ('DE', 'Population',
         pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')): 4,
        ('DE', 'Population',
         pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')): 5,
        ('DE', 'Population',
         pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')): 6}}
).rename_axis(['country', 'category', 'date'])
```

`df`:

```
                                              Population (cap)
country category   date                                       
DE      Population 2018-01-01 00:00:00+00:00                 4
                   2019-01-01 00:00:00+00:00                 5
                   2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00                 6
FR      Population 2018-01-01 00:00:00+00:00                 1
                   2019-01-01 00:00:00+00:00                 2
                   2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00                 3
```

Comment: It works great ! It semmes I missed this part `as_index=False`

Answer (score 0):

I thought you could do this with pd.Grouper but it involves a fair amount of confusing tricks with keeping track of the other parts of the multiindex.

I think this could work as well, though it's not necessarily the most efficient due to the stack/unstack. Reordering and sorting the index aren't strictly necessary but I'm assuming they get the end result closer to what you're looking for.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Population (cap)': {
        ('FR', 'Population',
         pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')): 1,
        ('FR', 'Population',
         pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')): 2,
        ('FR', 'Population',
         pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')): 3,
        ('DE', 'Population',
         pd.Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')): 4,
        ('DE', 'Population',
         pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')): 5,
        ('DE', 'Population',
         pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')): 6}}
).rename_axis(['country', 'category', 'date'])

(
    df
    .unstack(['country', 'category'])
    .resample('3M').ffill()
    .stack(['country', 'category'])
    .reorder_levels(['country', 'category', 'date'])
    .sort_index()
)
```

Input looks like this:

[image: Input data]

Output looks like this:

[image: Output data]